# Bar charts in Scalala

Tags: scala, charts, scalala

Is it possible to use Scalala to plot bar charts, similars to http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bar.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot a [Histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) using Scalala. See [this link to Scalala API](http://www.scalanlp.org/docs/scalala/nightly/scalala/library/Plotting.html).

Comment: The function hist() is only useful to analyze the distribution of data values, similars to Matlab's hist() function. I need a more generic purpose bar chart plot function, similars to Matlab's bar().